# Verifying originality/unique-ness of idea- without stepping on the toes of another idea

Tags: verification

Am I able to submit an idea for a patent and then have a service that involves checking the originality of the idea / probability that it can be developed without interfering with other similar existing patents?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like one question but you are asking two questions somewhat twisted together.

One question is how do you assess the chances of getting a patent on your clever concept. People usually have a novelty search on the clever concept done by a professional searcher or work with a patent attorney or patent agent who might do the search in house or might subcontract with a search company. A searcher can find things and send to you but not give an opinion. Of course the patent office will also do a search as part of deciding if a patent is deserved.

The other question is if you ship your complete product - clever parts and ordinary parts - will the the complete product or some part of it infringe on an in force patent. For this you need a search called a clearance search or a freedom to operate search on all aspects of the shipping product, not just the part you think is clever.

The two answers are complete separate. It could be yes/no, no/yes, yes/yes or no/no.